# MySQL remove uuid function from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that was inherited from a different system and one of the fields has the UUID function enabled so no matter what ID I generate and try to insert, the table creates a completely different one automatically.

I would like to use a PHP function to create the ID instead but I can't workout how to remove the UUID function from the field.

I am not sure what information will be needed to help you so please feel free to ask.

The field in question is

`id, char(36)`

Table definaition is..

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(60) default NULL,
`user_hash` varchar(32) default NULL,
`diary_weekly_view` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`week_start` date NOT NULL,
`diary_monthly_view` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`diary_view` int(1) NOT NULL default '1',
`account_search` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`cases_search` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`serials_search` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`notes` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
`authenticate_id` varchar(100) default NULL,
`sugar_login` tinyint(1) default '1',
`first_name` varchar(30) default NULL,
`last_name` varchar(30) default NULL,
`reports_to_id` char(36) default NULL,
`is_admin` tinyint(1) default '0',
`receive_notifications` tinyint(1) default '1',
`date_entered` datetime NOT NULL,
`date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified_user_id` char(36) default NULL,
`created_by` char(36) default NULL,
`phone_office` varchar(50) default NULL,
`phone_mobile` varchar(50) default NULL,
`status` varchar(25) default NULL,
`address_street` varchar(150) default NULL,
`address_city` varchar(100) default NULL,
`address_state` varchar(100) default NULL,
`address_country` varchar(25) default NULL,
`address_postalcode` varchar(9) default NULL,
`user_preferences` text,
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`portal_only` tinyint(1) default '0',
`employee_status` varchar(25) default NULL,
`is_group` tinyint(1) default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
```

Comment: Please show the table definition. Is a trigger defined too?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and paste it here. Also, check if there are any triggers associated with the table in question.

Comment: The `uuid` is not in the table definition. A trigger is probably generating it when the insert happens.

Comment: I have run show triggers and there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sussed it, I removed the index and then recreated the index with `INDEX`